# $u(x, t)$ of \begin{equation} \begin{cases} u_t = k u_{xx} + u \\ u(x, 0) = f(x) \end{cases} \end{equation}

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

How do I use a Fourier transform to find a formula for the solution $u(x, t)$ of

\begin{equation}
    \begin{cases}
      u_t = k u_{xx} + u \\
      u(x, 0) = f(x)
    \end{cases}
  \end{equation}

where $−∞ < x < ∞$, $t > 0$, in terms of $f(x)$ and $k$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Let

$$U(k,t) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \, u(x,t) e^{i k x}$$

Then, taking Fourier transforms

$$u_t = \kappa u_{xx} + u \implies U_t = -(\kappa k^2-1) U \implies U(k,t) = U(k,0)e^{-(\kappa k^2-1) t}$$
$$U(k,0) = F(k) \implies U(k,t) = F(k) e^{-(\kappa k^2-1) t}$$

To invert the FT, use the convolution theorem.  We of course need the FT of the gaussian term:

$$\frac1{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, e^{-\kappa t k^2} e^{-i k x} = \frac1{2 \pi}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\kappa t}} e^{-x^2/(4 \kappa t)}$$

$$u(x,t) = e^t \frac1{2 \pi} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\kappa t}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx' \, f(x') \, e^{-(x-x')^2/(4 \kappa t)} $$

Comment: I understand everything here except solving the convolution theorem.  How do I apply that?

Comment: @Jimm: I erred in my previous answer.  It is now corrected.  Maybe it will be more clear now.

Comment: I actually have a solution to the problem which is similar to yours, but I just can't seem to follow the logic of how to calculate the Gaussian term.

Comment: @Jimm: Complete the square in the exponential.  You get something like $$-\kappa t \left (k^2+i \frac{x}{\kappa t} k - \frac{x^2}{4 \kappa^2 t^2} \right )  - \frac{x^2}{4 \kappa t} $$  Then use $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dk \, e^{-a k^2} = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} $$